# What does the word "turn-in" in "Turn-in instructions" mean?

Tags: american-english

I have run into that phrase when I read a homework assignment. I can't find any clear explanation on the internet. I only see "in-turn" instead. Please help me understand that. If you need the context document, I will post it.

Comment: As CopperKettle says, a [compound adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) has been formed by adding a hyphen to “turn in”. “Turn-in instructions” could also be rewritten as “instructions for turning in (your assignment)”.

Comment: Thanks for *compound adjective*, @TylerJamesYoung! I've been looking for the correct name. I knew that when a noun is used adjectivally it is a "noun adjunct" and tried to find what do we call a phrasal verb used in the same way.

Comment: It's a slightly quirky usage, so one can hardly blame OP for not understanding it straight away. But (particularly if we can assume OP isn't the only non-native speaker in the class) there's certainly scope for being critical of whoever used it in the first place. It's not a usage you'd want to encourage over *[homework assignment] **submission** instructions*, so if you can't rely on it being more easily understood, why use it in the first place?

Comment: If I had known the grammar point mentioned in the answer, I would have understood that easily. I would have looked up the word "to turn in" instead.
Thank you all.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Maybe PO was mistakenly assigned to a group of advanced English language learners, and the others caught the meaning quickly in the group. :) So, there can be a reason of why this tutor used this word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Turn-in instructions" probably means

> Instructions for submitting your completed homework for grading.

The verb ["to turn in"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_in) means "to submit, to give". In your sentence, this verb is transformed into an adjective "turn-in". Hence,

> What kind of instructions? - *Turn-in* instructions.